# How do i make CSV file out in a column match

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a awk script which reads a file ad prints output, the last 3 columns were merged together, when the script runs, the merged columns is suppose to have 18 digits, where is it not up to 18 digits it should be filled with zeros to match the required format.

This is my CSV file which the awk script reads:

```
Account number (preferred / formatted),Customer reference,Posting date,Account currency,Transaction amount
750856653,233420,3/9/2019,USD,-2092.99
750856653,233417,3/9/2019,USD,-2856.15
750856653,233426,3/9/2019,USD,-2392.25
750856653,233414,3/9/2019,USD,-1733.22
750856653,233424,3/9/2019,USD,-1850.31
750856653,233403,3/9/2019,USD,-1850.32
750856653,233413,3/9/2019,USD,-1439.58
750856653,233431,3/9/2019,USD,-186.66
```

this is my current output when the script runs:
(The last column should have 18 digits but like the first 3 rows on the last column.)

```
750-85665-3 0000233446  09162019000000230644
750-85665-3 0000233435  09162019000000173321
750-85665-3 0000233442  09162019000000219319
750-85665-3 0000233443  0916201900000097416
750-85665-3 0000233429  0918201900000069263
750-85665-3 0000233447  092320190000006619
750-85665-3 0000233450  092320190000001461
750-85665-3 0000233451  0923201900000035631
```

My code:

```
  awk '
  BEGIN{ FS=","
   }
  FNR==1{
  print
   next
 }
   $2!~/NONREF/{
    $1=substr($1,1,3)"-"substr($1,4,5)"-"substr($1,length($1))
$2="0000"$2
split($3,array,"/")
    $3=sprintf("%02d%02d%s",array[2],array[1],array[3])
gsub(/^-|\./,"",$NF)
     $3=$3"000000"$NF
  print $1,$2,$3
  }
  '  Input_file
```

This is my desired output how i want the last column to be , all 18 digits with zeros filled in.

```
750-85665-3  0000219839 090519000000017170
750-85665-3  0000233423 090519000000087349
750-85665-3  0000233416 090619000000047765
750-85665-3  0000233425 090619000000129305
750-85665-3  0000233421 090919000000199722
750-85665-3  0000219838 091019000000026502
750-85665-3  0000233415 091019000000169140
750-85665-3  0000233419 091119000000099291
750-85665-3  0000233433 091319000000188880
750-85665-3  0000233438 091319000000296821
750-85665-3  0000233452 091619000000323724
750-85665-3  0000233441 091619000000190742
750-85665-3  0000233446 091619000000230644
```

EDIT(by Ravinder):  this looks follow up question for [CSV file output is not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58543236/csv-file-output-is-not-correct) one, though OP still needs to add samples for all users understanding purposes,thought to add it here.

Comment: What does the input file look like?

Comment: Could you please post exact Input_file in CODE TAGS and let us know then?

Comment: What is going on in your code? Can you add comments and explanations? Assuming `$NF` is a number after that `gsub(/^-|\./,"",$NF)` I think you can just `printf "%6d%12d", $3, $NF`

Comment: Please fix your code to use reasonable indenting so we don't have to work harder than necessary to understand it. Also make sure the expected output you post is the output you expect from the input you post, not the output you'd expect from some other set of input that you haven't shown us, amnd that your example makes sense with respect to the code you post - there's nothing in your input/output that'd explain/warrant code that tests for `FNR==1`, nor for `$2!~/NONREF/`.

Comment: There's also nothing in your example to explain why your code is splitting on `/`, nor gsub-ing on `/^-|\./`. Either your code is completely wrong or your example is wrong as the 2 aren't related.

Comment: @EdMorton, hello Ed sir, yes you are right, OP hasn't mentioned actual Input_file details it is the output of a command not correct Input_file. Since I helped OP in previous thread, I thought to add that link too here. But I totally agree on it that OP has to provide complete details in post sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per OP, to insert spaces between 1st and 2nd column try following.

```
awk -v s1="      " '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
}
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
$2!~/NONREF/{
  $1=substr($1,1,3)"-"substr($1,4,5)"-"substr($1,length($1))
  $2=sprintf("%010d",$2)
  split($3,array,"/")
  $3=sprintf("%02d%02d%s",array[2],array[1],substr(array[3],3))
  gsub(/^-|\./,"",$NF)
  $NF=sprintf("%012d",$NF)
  $3=$3 $NF
  print $1 s1 $2,$3
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

After going through previous post of OP, could you please try following. Which will make sure that your new 3rd column will have 18 digits(8 for date + 10 digits from last Field including zeros).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
}
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
$2!~/NONREF/{
  $1=substr($1,1,3)"-"substr($1,4,5)"-"substr($1,length($1))
  $2=sprintf("%010d",$2)
  split($3,array,"/")
  $3=sprintf("%02d%02d%s",array[2],array[1],substr(array[3],3))
  gsub(/^-|\./,"",$NF)
  $NF=sprintf("%012d",$NF)
  $3=$3 $NF
  print $1,$2,$3
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: you are a genius, it works . thanks. how to i add more spaces between columns?

Comment: @jaybiano, Glad that it helped you, I would like to request you to FIX your question, so that people are able to understand it properly, since I helped you previously I am some what aware of it but NOT all. So at first place please do EDIT your question correctly and let us know then.'

Comment: @jaybiano, You could append `|   column -t` after my code and it will make TAB as a separator in output too.

Comment: @RavinderSigh13, what question would you like me to edit, the previous one?

Comment: i fixed it. also i noticed output date format does not match. date should be 2 digits month, 2 digits day and 2 digit year. example is : 090519 but my output has date as 09052019. 4 digit year.   6 digits for date and amount 12 digits filled with zeros which makes total 18digits.

Comment: @jaybiano, Sure, I have edited code accordingly now. 6 digits for date and 12 for rest(new 3rd field), kindly do lemme know in case of any queries here, cheers(I hope we should be good here).

Comment: its perfect. last one, how do i make 6 spaces between the first and second column ?   Example is                                                                                    
750-85665-3       0000233425 090619000000129305

Comment: @jaybiano, could you please try `| column -t` appending this after my posted code and see if that helps you?

Comment: the | column -t work but it create space between all columns, i want the multiple spaces to be between the first and second column only not affecting the third column.

Comment: @jaybiano, Could you please check my EDIT code and lemme know if this helps you?  Looks ok to me.